# C program with MQ get a message MQGET ended with reason code 2005

Tags: c, ibm-mq

I made and run the C program, which connect to MQ and try to get a message. I always get a message:

```
         MQGET ended with reason code 2005
```

this means:

```
           MQRC_BUFFER_LENGTH_ERROR (2005, X'7D5') Buffer length parameter not valid
```

I declared the buffer as

```
           char     TempBuf[65536];
```

The message in MQ is

```
            "This is a test message"
```

in MQ error log nothing is written.

Below is the program:

```
               **/* header files */**    
               #include <stdio.h>   
               #include <stdlib.h>      
               #include <string.h>      

               #include <cmqc.h>      /* includes for MQI*/              
               #include <cmqxc.h>   

               int main(int argc, char **argv)    
               {
               MQCNO   Connect_options = {MQCNO_DEFAULT};/MQNONNX opt*/   
               MQCD    ClientConn = {MQCD_CLIENT_CONN_DEFAULT};/*client channel*/  
               MQHCONN  Hcon;                   /* connection handle  */  
               MQHOBJ   Hobj;                   /* object handle */   
               MQLONG   CompCode;               /* completion code  */   
               MQLONG   OpenCode;               /* MQOPEN completion code*/  
               MQLONG   Reason;                 /* reason code    */   
               MQOD     od = {MQOD_DEFAULT};    /* Object Descriptor */   
               MQMD     md = {MQMD_DEFAULT};    /* Message Descriptor */   
               MQPMO    pmo = {MQPMO_DEFAULT};  /* put message options*/   
               MQLONG   O_options;              /* MQOPEN options  */   
               MQLONG   C_options;              /* MQCLOSE options */   
               MQGMO   gmo = {MQGMO_DEFAULT};   /* get message options */   

               char     QMgrName[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH+1];
               char     QName[MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH+1];
               char     channelName[MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH+1];
               char     hostname[1024];
               char     port[4];
               MQLONG   buflen;        /* buffer length*/
               char TempBuf[65536];
               int msgsToGet;
               int msgsGot;

               if (argc != 6)   
               {   
                printf("Usage: MQTest11 QMgrName ChlName hostname port  QName\n");   
                return(1);   
               }    

               **/* copy MQ manager name */**   
               strncpy(QMgrName, argv[1], MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH);    
               QMgrName[MQ_Q_MGR_NAME_LENGTH] = '\0';    

               **/* copy channel name */**
               strncpy(channelName, argv[2], MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH);    
               channelName[MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH] = '\0';    

               /* copy hostname */
               strncpy(hostname, argv[3], 1023);    
               hostname[1023] = '\0'; 

               /* copy port number */   
               strncpy(port,argv[4],4);    
               strncpy(QName, argv[5], MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH);    
               QName[MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH] = '\0';    

               /* copy hostname for connection */
               strncpy(ClientConn.ConnectionName,hostname, MQ_CONN_NAME_LENGTH);    

               /* copy channel name */
               strncpy(ClientConn.ChannelName,channelName,MQ_CHANNEL_NAME_LENGTH);   

               /* Point the MQCNO to the client connection definition */   
               Connect_options.ClientConnPtr = &ClientConn;    
               Connect_options.Version = MQCNO_VERSION_2;    

               /* use MQCONNX */    

               if (CompCode == MQCC_FAILED)    
               {   
                    /* exit with print the reason */    
               }    
               else    
               {    
                strncpy(od.ObjectName, QName, (size_t)MQ_Q_NAME_LENGTH);    
                O_options = MQOO_OUTPUT + MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;    
                /* use MQOPEN */    

                if (OpenCode == MQCC_OK)    /* if MQOPEN , then continue in the while loop */      
                {    
                gmo.Options = MQGMO_WAIT + MQGMO_CONVERT;    
                gmo.WaitInterval = 15000;    
                msgsGot = 0;    
                msgsToGet = 0;    

                }    
                 while (CompCode != MQCC_FAILED && ((msgsToGet == 0) || (msgsGot < msgsToGet)))    
                {   

               /* define length of the buffer -1 */   
               buflen = strlen(TempBuf) - 1;    */ buffer length */
               memcpy(md.MsgId, MQMI_NONE, sizeof(md.MsgId)); /*copy msg ID*/     
               memcpy(md.CorrelId, MQCI_NONE, sizeof(md.CorrelId));/*copy corrlID*/      
               md.Encoding       = MQENC_NATIVE; /*encode*/   
               md.CodedCharSetId = MQCCSI_Q_MGR;   

               /* function to get message from MQ*/
               MQGET(Hcon,       /* get message from MQ */   
               Hobj,             /* object handle*/   
               &md,              /* message descriptor*/   
               &gmo,             /*get message options*/    
               buflen,           /*buffer length*/   
               TempBuf,          /* buffer */   
               &messlen,         /* message length*/   
               &CompCode,       /* completion code*/   
               &Reason);         /* reason code*/   

             **/* I put some statements to check if transaction failed or not*/**    
               if (Reason != MQRC_NONE)     
               {   
               if (Reason == MQRC_NO_MSG_AVAILABLE)   
               {   
               /* print statement no more messages */   
               else   
               {   
                 printf("MQGET ended with reason code %d comcode %d\n",Reason,CompCode);       
                if (Reason == MQRC_TRUNCATED_MSG_FAILED)    
                {   
                 /print statement that it is failed*/    
                }     
                }   
                }   

               **/* This is almost done, only statement if Compcode not failed, then print buffer */**
```

The buffer is not printed and error message you can see above. 
I appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The error code tells you that the problem is with the buffer length parameter. Please post more of your code so we can see how the buflen variable is defined.

Comment: There problem that I couldn't format correctly my post. I will edit it now.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in my answer?

Comment: @JoshMc, sorry I don't see your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buffer should be of type `MQBYTE` not `char`:

**Change:** `char   TempBuf[65536];`
**To:** `MQBYTE TempBuf[65536];`

To get the buffer length you should use `sizeof` not `strlen`.

**Change:** `buflen = strlen(TempBuf) - 1;`
**To:** `buflen = sizeof(TempBuf)-1;`

Comment: what do you mean by that? Do I have to declare Tempbuf as char? or something is wrong with buflen?

Comment: I DECLARED IT AS MQBYTE. the same error MQGET ended with reason code 2005 comcode 2

Comment: Now I have tested program and it says "Sucessfully connected", " MQOPEN CC=0 RC=0", MQGET ended with reason code 2037 comcode 2. Please check what is wrong with my code

Comment: You should not update your code in your question with the corrected code, you should leave it incorrect since that is part of the question and the answers would not make sense with out it.  You should accept my answer if that helped you over come the 2005 error.  You should post a new question with the corrected code showing the new 2037 error.

Comment: I corrected it back. Please check my new post https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350835/c-program-with-mq-get-a-message-mqget-ended-with-reason-code-2037

Comment: Thank you.  If you agree that my answer helped you overcome the initial 2005 error them please accept it and by clicking the "check mark" to the left of the answer below the down arrow.  Also note that the new question you posted was posted incorrectly the Meta site not the main stackoverflow site, please delete it on Meta and post on the main site.  Please also make sure to tag it with the tag [[tag:ibm-mq]].

Comment: I will do it, however, I cannot ask the questions anymore. They don't allow me to ask questions. Could you please still help me with error 2037 here?